# The verification could not be sent to NeverBounce

Tags: zapier, email-verification, zapier-cli

I am new at Zapier and trying to make an email verification using NeverBounce from Zapier and complete the following setup.

1. I create an app in NeverBounce.
2. I complete Trigger in steps in Zapier.
3. Completed the Action and logged in NeverBounce by IP key.

And finally, during testing, I get this error!

```
The verification could not be sent to NeverBounce.
The app returned `{"message":"We were unable to complete your request. Check our system status at https://twitter.com/neverbounceapi as their may be an issue with our system. The following information was supplied: Insufficient credit balance.
```

[Here is an screen shoot of the error I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTLZN.jpg)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says you don't have enough credits, you may want to check your account. Or this may be just a glitch with the test procedure and you may want to just proceed with the Zap and see if the actual run is successful.

As an alternative, you may want to switch to Verifalia instead, which not only includes daily credits even with its free plan but also allows to [verify lists of email addresses](https://verifalia.com/help/zapier-integration/verify-list-of-email-addresses-zap-action) through Zapier (in addition to single email verification).

- Verifalia integrations: https://verifalia.com/integrations
- Verifalia Zapier integration: https://zapier.com/apps/verifalia/integrations

Disclaimer: I work for Verifalia and have developed its Zapier integration.